# How to calculate the position of a fluid parcel knowing the Eulerian velocity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, reference-frames, velocity, flow

I know the velocity of a fluid, $V(\mathbf x,t)$ for each fixed point $\mathbf x$ and time $t$. From this information, I want to calculate the position in time, $L(t)$, of a fluid parcel that was at position $L_0$ at time $t=t_0$. How do I calculate this?

Comment: Just to clarify. The velocity is in eulerian coordinates and i want to calculate the position of a fluid parcel which is in lagrangian coordinates.

Comment: Just apply this concept (see the answe of Chet Miller) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_curve

Answer (score 2):

You solve the ordinary differential equation (in component form) $$\frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt}=\mathbf{V(\mathbf{x},t)}$$subject to the initial condition $$\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x_0}$$at t = 0.